# How do I find the path for a failed python import?

Tags: python, exception, module

Let's say I have a module which fails to import (there is an exception when importing it).

eg. `test.py` with the following contents:

```
print 1/0
```

*[Obviously, this isn't my actual file, but it will stand in as a good proxy]*

Now, at the python prompt:

```
>>> import test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
```

**What's the best way to find the path/file location of `test.py`?**

[I could iterate through [Python's module search path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) looking in each directory for the file, but I'd think there must be a simpler way...]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module. It has a function, [`imp.find_module()`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.find_module), which receives as a parameter the name of a module and returns a tuple, whose second item is the path to the module:

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module('test') # A file I created at my current dir
(<open file 'test.py', mode 'U' at 0x8d84e90>, 'test.py', ('.py', 'U', 1))
>>> imp.find_module('sys')  # A system module
(None, 'sys', ('', '', 6))
>>> imp.find_module('lxml') # lxml, which I installed with pip
(None, '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml', ('', '', 5))
>>> imp.find_module('lxml')[1]
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml'
```

Comment: Perfect.  I knew there had to be a simple answer (just couldn't find it)!

Comment: What a devilishly simple approach.